# Binary to Decimal Converter with Char Arrays

Tags: c++, gcc

Creating a binary to decimal converter; have most of the bare bones down but I have a problem - the program reads the binary number from left to right instead of right to left (as one would normally do with computing it through handwriting). Because of this, inputs such as '1111', '10001', and 10101', come out as their correct decimal answers, but some inputs such as '10011' would obviously come out incorrect.

TL;DR Which way is most appropriate to flip how a loop goes through a char array?

Sample code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 33 && binary[i] != '\0'; i++, power++)
{
  if (binary[i] == '0')
    continue;

  else if (binary[i] == '1')
    decimal = pow (2,power) + decimal;

  else
  {
  cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
  return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks from the code you have written above that either your string will be exactly 33 digits, or if it is shorter it will be null terminated. I only ask because that's a bit odd, and it would better if (for instance) you could make it always null terminated. That would simplify the code.

But if that's how it is then the following code should work

```
// find the number of digits
int num_digits = 0;
while (num_digits < 33 && binary[num_digits] != '\0')
    ++num_digits;

// now we have the number of digits we can ...
// ... loop backwards through the string
for (int i = num_digits; i > 0; )
{
    --i;
    if (binary[i] == '0')
        continue;

    else if (binary[i] == '1')
        decimal = pow (2,power) + decimal;

    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid input." << endl;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I see the other answers you have received are assuming that your string is always null terminated. If that's true then you should go with one of those answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following to read the array from the end to the beginning,

```
int pos_of_zero = strlen(binary);

for(int i = pos_of_zero - 1; i > -1;  --i, power++)
{
   // ....
```

Comment: Would this replace my other for loop? Because when I attempt this I get "Invalid Input" every time.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following

```
for (i = strlen(binary) - 1; i >= 0; --i) {

}
```

In this manner, if you have a binary number "10011", the for loop would go through the bits in this order: 1 -> 1 -> 0 -> 0 -> 1.

You could compute the decimal value of a binary number in a more efficient way by avoiding calls to the pow function.

```
for (int i = 0, decimal = 0; i < strlen(binary); ++i)
    decimal = decimal*2 + (binary[i] - '0');
```

Comment: Same as the other answer, I get 'Invalid Input' every time.

Comment: You need to adapt the portion of code I gave to fit your implementation. You are probably accessing a position i of the binary array which is not part of the binary number. What I tried to say is that, your for loop can either go from 0 to (size_of_binary - 1) or from (size_of_binary - 1) to 0. Or you can still go from 0 to (size_of_binary -1) and calculate the decimal value using the formula decimal = decimal*2 + (binary[i] - '0'), which avoids calling pow() many times.